# Subclassing NSPredicate to add operator

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspredicate, subclassing

Cocoa defines predicate classes (`NSPredicate`, `NSExpression`, etc.) which *"provide a general means of specifying queries in Cocoa"* <sup>[Predicate Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1)</sup>. This set of classes describes what I need but with one little short-coming : I'd like additional operators.

`NSComparisonPredicate` already handles 14 operators ([NSPredicateOperatorType](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSComparisonPredicate_Class/Reference/NSComparisonPredicate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001189-BBCHHCAD)) but I would like to add, say, temporal operators... or operators to represent things such as:

- " *variable* **has at least** *n* **entries**" *(binary operator)*
- " *variable* **has** *value* **for, at most,** *n* **consecutive days**" *(ternary operator)*

Obviously, I would need to implement these myself and the data model on which such queries are performed will have to support these operators. But, is there a way to implement it and benefit from the existing NSPredicate classes?  Since operators were defined as an `enum`, I doubt I can extend on that front.  Or am I completely missing the boat on this?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Having](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1482915398/localizing-nspredicateeditor) [spent](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1488710860/followup-to-localizing-nspredicateeditor) [a](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1553469975/abusing-nspredicate) [lot](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1646098126/creating-a-simple-nspredicateeditorrowtemplate) [of](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1677163679/creating-an-advanced-nspredicateeditorrowtemplate) [time](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1677163679/creating-an-advanced-nspredicateeditorrowtemplate) [playing](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/2922267976/using-custom-functions-with-nsexpression) [around](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/2726166818/what-the-heck-is-subquery) [with](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/7289992438/dumbfounded) `NSPredicate`, I'm not sure this is the greatest idea.

*Theoretically*, you'd subclass `NSPredicate`, create your new initializer and properties, and then override the `-evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:` method to do your custom comparison.

Practically, it's probably a lot more difficult than that.

You might consider using `FUNCTION()` instead.  [I wrote a blog post about `FUNCTION`](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/2922267976/using-custom-functions-with-nsexpression) a while ago and how it plays with `NSExpression` and therefore with `NSPredicate`.  Personally, I'd probably go with this, because then you could still use the `+predicateWithFormat:` syntax to create the `NSPredicate`.  Creating a subclass to add an operator would necessarily prevent you from using the built-in parser.